# ColdFusion 9 - File Write detection (anti-exploit)

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, exploit

I have a web server (IIS 7) with ~400,000 files on it.
80,000 of these are .cfm files.
I believe that one of those files is permitting an exploit whereby a file can be uploaded anywhere in wwwroot.

I think this because I enabled windows auditing, and see that the file generated has an event log specifying JRun.exe as the culprit. It is definitely written to disk by Jrun.

I need to know the best way to determine which coldfusion script running inside Jrun's singular instance is causing the file to be written to disk.

I am about to override the *java.io* namespace, **unless someone here has a better idea**. And yes, I ran PowerGREP utility to scan all files for file write strings, such as:

- CFIDE.componentutils.cfcexplorer
- action="upload"      (+single quotes, and ="write")
- java.io
- BufferedWriter
  etc

The exploit I'm seeing appear in numbers is: http://pastebin.com/sNGycNZS
Simple google search by content yielded it.

Comment: This sounds like the h.cfm exploit that is a part of the /cfide/administrator. Is your admin resolvable to the outside world or restricted to 127.0.0.1 (or secured in some other way)?

Comment: Hello thank you for the reply, I am really at wits end for this and appreciate any suggestions. I think you may be onto something, our host provider has a security team that identified a problem within the CFIDE directory, and removed it, but it didn't solve this yet.

As for your question specifically, no it is restricted only to localhost, which is protected by VPN. It's a Private server too, so it's not a shared host with other access points. So even if this exploit revealed database passwords, etc, they can't use them. Not natively anyway.

Comment: Yeah - once the exploit is used you then have other files installed with elevated permissions - not necessarily CF files either. cs files are common - rootkits - that sort of thing. Unfortunately once corrupted our recommendation is typically to create a pristine install in another instance, lock it down, then migrate JUST the known, clean CF code to it. Wish I had better advice.

Comment: I agree with Mark. Once you've been exploited like this... you are best served by building a new server and scrapping that one. The amount of time it'll take to track it down is likely to be be more than just rebuilding. Also you will never *really* know whether you've completely sanitised the box, if you try to clean it up. For future reference: never ever EVER leave the /CFIDE dir publicly exposed on a CF server. I guess you know that now :-(

Comment: Thank you guys really appreciate the assistance. I am performing a "hook" on the FileOutputStream in the java.io namespace, and having it log events into windows event log with the stacktrace. Not elegant, but if Coldfusion is writing files, I'm about to find out "who" it is. Even so, I tend to agree that it's definitely best to start fresh. I will let you know of results :)   - Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, so I ended up decompiling java.io.FileOutputStream.class inside Coldfusion\runtime\jre\lib\rt.jar
And patching it to log to the event log for each function that performs the Write() function.

```
public FileOutputStream(String paramString)
throws FileNotFoundException{  // aka @override
    this(paramString != null ? new File(paramString) : null, false);
    DoEvent("_Single_", "FileOutputStream(" + paramString + "): ");
}

// my attempt at forcing line breaks in through command prompt were insufficient. So I used regex after-the-fact to replace %NL% with \r\n. :P
public static void DoEvent(String type, String description)  {
if (description.contains("wwwroot"))
{
  StackTraceElement[] stack = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace();
  StringBuilder sz = new StringBuilder();
  String linefeed = "%NL%";
  for (StackTraceElement s : stack)
  {
    sz.append(s.toString());
    sz.append(linefeed + "-------------" + linefeed);
  }
  description = description + linefeed + sz.toString();
  String command = "cmd /c \"SET NLM=^\r\n\r\n && set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM% && ";
  command = command + "eventcreate  /l APPLICATION /so \"COLDFUSION FILE WRITE :: " + type + " " + "\"" + " /t " + "ERROR" + " /id " + new Random().nextInt(500) + " /d \"" + description + "\"";

  command = command + "\"";
  try
  {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
  }
  catch (IOException e) {}
}
```

Which yielded results:

```
FileOutputStream(E:\.....\wwwroot\public\subdomain.site.com\images\veryver.cfm):
java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1479)
^--> java.io.FileOutputStream.DoEvent(FileOutputStream.java:26)
^--> java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:75)
^--> java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:60)
^--> coldfusion.vfs.VFSFileFactory.fetchOutputStream(VFSFileFactory.java:442)
^--> coldfusion.vfs.VFSFileFactory.getOutputStream(VFSFileFactory.java:283)
^--> coldfusion.tagext.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:944)
^--> coldfusion.tagext.io.FileUtils$2.run(FileUtils.java:613)
^--> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
^--> coldfusion.tagext.io.FileUtils.uploadFile(FileUtils.java:609)
^--> coldfusion.tagext.io.FileTag.upload(FileTag.java:591)
^--> coldfusion.tagext.io.FileTag.doStartTag(FileTag.java:266)
^--> coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2722)
^--> cftvb2ecfm60673673._factor26(E:\....\wwwroot\CFIDE\scripts\tvb.cfm:468)
^--> cftvb2ecfm60673673._factor27(E:\....\wwwroot\CFIDE\scripts\tvb.cfm:466)
^--> cftvb2ecfm60673673._factor28(E:\....\wwwroot\CFIDE\scripts\tvb.cfm:465)
^--> cftvb2ecfm60673673._factor29(E:\....\wwwroot\CFIDE\scripts\tvb.cfm:464)
^--> cftvb2ecfm60673673._factor121(E:\....\wwwroot\CFIDE\scripts\tvb.cfm:462)
^--> cftvb2ecfm60673673._factor124(E:\....\wwwroot\CFIDE\scripts\tvb.cfm:76)
^--> cftvb2ecfm60673673._factor125(E:\....\wwwroot\CFIDE\scripts\tvb.cfm:72)
^--> cftvb2ecfm60673673.runPage(E:\....\wwwroot\CFIDE\scripts\tvb.cfm:1)
^--> coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:231)
^--> coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:416)
^--> coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
^--> coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:387)
^--> coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:48)
^--> coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
^--> coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:94)
^--> coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
^--> coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
^--> coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
^--> coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
^--> coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
^--> coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
^--> coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
^--> coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)
^--> coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:201)
^--> coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
^--> jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)
^--> coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
^--> coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
^--> jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)
^--> jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)
^--> jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
^--> jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
^--> jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
^--> jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
^--> jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
^--> jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
^--> jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
^--> jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
^--> jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
^-->
```

So as you can see, it was a remnant script located in CFIDE. Not sure how they accessed it, because it's outside of the scope of public accessible documents.
You have to have VPN access AND remote desktop, just to access CFIDE.

Anyway, so I solved this by removing the file. 
Please also note that I used this same method to trace what wrote the above mentioned file, and determined it to be a compiled coldfusion class inside the Coldfusion classes/cache folder.
E:\ColdFusion9\wwwroot\WEB-INF\cfclasses\

I deleted it to be safe, though the code seems quite docile when decompiled.
i would also recommend everyone to check their system's scheduled tasks, as well as coldfusion's scheduled tasks, and any cf probes.

In order to assist others in finding this content, here are some strings for google (ordered by frequency of occurrence within infected file --- scan in *.php,*.cf?, and *.class):

- S?bastien Denis
- CFIDE.componentutils.cfcexplorer
- hermes
- Silence is golden

And the most-common files:

- veryver.cfm
- img.cfm
- co.cfm
- as.cfm
- good.cfm
- z.txt

And the targets of the attack:

- index.php
- Wordpress
- file_get_contents('http://www.mqa.gov.my/fpdb/hermes_kopi.htm');
- window.location.href="http://www.22sougo.com/hermes-birkin25-1.htm"

I'd like to have attached the source code to that .class i spoke of, but can't seem to find the option on this site. Probably for the better that I don't share the source of it anyway.

Thanks for the help all :)